# DEC (probably PDP-11) operating system with a guest mode allowing to run BASIC programs

Tags: pdp-11, identify-this-software

In the mid 1970's I used an OS on DEC equipment (I believe PDP-11) that had a guest mode. If you weren't an authorised user you could login as guest mode where you supplied a name and if it didn't exist it was created with a password and if it did exist you entered your password and then had access to a BASIC 'environment' where you could create/compile/execute/save BASIC programs. In guest mode when you logged out for each file/program stored you had to confirm that you wanted to keep that file/program. I don't know the capabilities for an authorised user as I only ever used it in guest mode.

Does anyone have any information about this system please?

Comment: Here is a [comprehensive list of PDP-11 operating systems](http://www.dbit.com/pub/pdp11/faq/faq.pages/pdpOSes.html). Do you recognise any of the names on that list?

Comment: Discounting some of the less likely options in that list, my uninformed guess at this stage is that it might be RSTS as it booted into BASIC and many of the OS programs were written in BASIC (technically, "BASIC-PLUS"). MTS is another possibility, although I think RSTS (or a variant) would have been more likely. I couldn't find any reference to a "guest" mode or login in either OS though.

Comment: @Noel. I didn't know the name of the os then so I won't recognise it now. That's the main reason for this question to try to identify its name.

Comment: @Noel. It wasn't RSTS/RT11 as I used RSTS later and I knew it well. RSTS didn't have a guest mode and the login id was a number pair. Might have been RSX/TSX (when did they become available as this was about 1976-1978). Did these have a guest mode? It was this guest mode that is intriguing to me.

Comment: RSX-11M had a "USER" account that was designed as a sandbox environment for learning how the OS worked. What might provide some context is **where** you remember using this system, was it at a university or a business? This feature does sound like the kind of thing that would be included in a university distribution, or at least a university might customise it to work like that, and the straight-into-BASIC mode sounds like it's not UN*X. This is all conjecture, unfortunately. Plus, it's possible that this feature might be undocumented in the operating manuals if it's a custom thing.

Comment: That list is not complete as it doesn't include MONECS, DEAMON or the rename as SCUBA. Although those systems allowed public access to BASIC they were exclusively Marksense or Punch Card only operating systems without a requirement for a username or password.

Comment: @Noel It was at a University when I was at school. I was allowed physical access to a terminal for 2 hours on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: @PDP11 - For this guest access the user initially provided a name which had to be unique. Once a unique name had been entered you then provided a password. If you entered a user name you were asked for the password. There was no intervention from any admin etc. 'Proper' users were administrated by the admin users. But as I was never given this level of access I have no idea what were the capabilities/languages available to these non-guest users. I have a vague memory of 'permissions' being discussed by them as we were all in the same largish room.

Comment: Any chance it was VAX/VMS?

Comment: I don't think the time-line fits. The VAX-11/780 was introduced October 25, 1977 and I was using this system from late 1976. At the time I didn't know what I was using other than it was DEC. When I was first given physical access to a terminal I was told to enter my name and if asked for an existing password to try another name. When you logged out you had to confirm for every stored file/program that you wanted to keep it. If you didn't confirm that file/program was deleted. I haven't come across this 'feature' again.

Comment: @hptsb A bit of a long shot, but have you tried looking on the university's web site? If the university was known for its computer science or physics departments at the time then there might be some archive material available related to it.

Comment: Yes - but the archive only discusses the initial establishment of the computer facilities (an Elliott 803 )

Comment: Sounds more like RSTS than RSX to me (as a programmer on both systems).  Since the source code for CUSPs was available, I suppose it would be pretty straightforward to replace the standard HELLO program with one that provided automatic account creation, so this was not necessarily a standard feature.

Comment: Also, the dialogue to specify the disposition of each file on logout was an option on TOPS-10 which was then replicated in RSTS, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Dave - I suppose RSTS is possible. RSTS has the BYE I command (ask for confirmation for each individual file) which if the os was modified might be made the default for guest access. As this was at a university, modification of this and the HELLO program (for automatic account creation from a user-name) would have been possible. The os commands I used and the Basic language used were the same (or very similar - as far as I remember [it's nearly 50 years ago!]) to those of RSTS and Basic-Plus.

Comment: Another possibility was that it was a home-grown login system. At my high school running DEC Multi-user BASIC on RT-11, rewriting the login system was a rite of passage. Do you remember anything about the filenames? With MUBasic in the 70s, your actual userid would be a two-character digit-letter combo, so a BASIC file might be saved as MYPROG.B1A.

Comment: @kdgregory - Sorry, I don't remember any other details. I don't even know the capabilities available to 'proper' users with authorised logon ids (or the format of these ids etc). I just had my 'guest' logon name which gave me access to a Basic programming environment.